# Wrap screen with hoc in Stacknavigator using React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i am try to using Context Api in react native.i want to wrap individual stack with global and child screen with consumer.
when i wrap whole App(root) container with context.Provider and wrap screen with Context.Consumer it work fine but problem is with individual stack.

```
    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
    screen:withGlobalContext(HomeScreen),
         // screen: SkillScreen,

    navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
        }},
    Skill: {
         screen: SkillScreen,
         navigationOptions: {
         header: null,
         tabBarVisible: false
         }
     },
    DetailOpp: {
    screen: OppDetailScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      tabBarVisible: false
     } }
    });

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="md-home" size={24} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
        // tabBarVisible :false
      }
    },

     <GlobalContextProvider>
        <AppContainer />
      </GlobalContextProvider>
```

like AppContainer it will work fine as expected but i want to wrap individual stack with provider